# How to use traverse with ExceptT and List so it returns Left only if all items are Left?

Tags: haskell, monads, traversal, monad-transformers

For example I have this function

```
foo :: Int -> ExceptT String (State Int) Int
foo x = if x == 0 then throwError "x == 0" else return x
```

and if I use `traverse`

```
evalState (runExceptT $ traverse foo [0,1,2]) 0
```

it returns

```
Left "x == 0"
```

But I want `Right [1,2]`
and it should return `Left` only when all list items are zero

Comment: What do you return for the empty list?

Comment: It my case it doesn't matter so it could be `Right` or `Left`

Comment: You may or may not find [`ExceptRT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.1.2/docs/Data-EitherR.html) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a question about `traverse` or do you just want to collect the results of `foo` which don't throw an exception?

The straight forward way do the latter is to run each invocation of `foo` in a "try-catch" block which returns a Maybe Int, and then `catMaybes` the list.

Example:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.State

foo :: Int -> ExceptT String (State Int) Int
foo x = if x == 0 then throwError "x == 0" else return x

orNothing p = catchError (fmap return p) (\e -> return Nothing)

collectFoos xs = do ys <- fmap catMaybes $ mapM (orNothing . foo) xs
                    case ys of
                      [] -> throwError "no successful call to foo"
                      _  -> return ys

doit xs = runState (runExceptT (collectFoos xs)) 100
```